# Crear archivos en /var/www/html/ Parrot OS

Tags: linux, apache

He terminado de instalar **Parrot OS** la versión completa, tuve varios problemas para lograr correr el servidor **apache** pero ya está listo, puedo crear y eliminar archivos en el directorio **/var/www/html/** (solo eso) el problema ocurre cuando intento **guardar** un archivo, me lanza el siguiente error: [image: Capture del error]

He visto problemas similares por el foro pero no me sirven las soluciones, así que no creo que sea pregunta duplicada.

Comment: Hola, ¿estás usando una cuenta de Super Usuario para escribir en ese directorio?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sí, hasta donde sé, sí.

Comment: puedes hacer un df -h para ver si tu sistema de archivos esta montado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un problema de permisos; debes hacerlo en modo root. Algo como esto:

```
sudo geany (ruta del archivo)
```

Comment: lo ideal es que cambie los permisos a www-data y el usuario pertenezca al grupo